# sed command with FTP access

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace multiple keywords by attempting to use `sed` on a remote FTP location.

```
sed -i -e 's/Squit/Use/g' ftp://server247.web-hosting.com/squit.io/index.html && sed -i -e 's/squit/ooze/g' ftp://server247.web-hosting.com/squit.io/index.html
```

I received an error that the folder isn't found.

Is that the right syntax for accessing remote folders with `sed`? Or probably there is a mistake in the folder included?

Comment: I highly doubt any version of `sed` can access a remote file directly.

Comment: @DarkFalcon are there similar tools to 'sed' as stream editors that can replace multiple keywords at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way on regular Unix-like systems to access remote files over `ftp` as if they were local. You might be able to find a virtual filesystem driver (google for FUSE) or operating system (Plan 9, Inferno?) which supports this; but then this becomes a question for the platform you choose, not about `sed` or U*x.

The standard solution would be to download the file, modify it locally, and upload it back to the original location.

```
curl 'ftp://server247.web-hosting.com/squit.io/index.html' |
sed -e 's/Squit/Use/g' -e 's/squit/ooze/g' >/tmp/squit.io.index.html
# Then upload it back somehow
```

Notice also the syntax for combining multiple `sed` commands in a single invocation. If indeed it were possible to edit remote files in-place, you would especially want to avoid the overhead of multiple round-trips and rewriting the file several times; but even for local processing, that's definitely something to always avoid if at all possible.